# How to use tuple inside of dictionary for named parameters in psycopg2

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to pass a tuple of values to use in a WHERE IN statement, and this is what cursor.mogrify() is returning to me:

```
b'SELECT site_id,site_name,date,time,* FROM "SiteInfoSchema"."Compressor" 
WHERE site_id in (\'TSE-000027, TSE-000032, TSE-000030, TSE-000031, TSE- 
000034, TSE-000033, TSE-000019, TSE-000020, TSE-000055, TSE-000021, TSE- 
000036, TSE-000035, TSE-000070, TSE-000003, TSE-000047, TSE-000029, TSE- 
000023, TSE-000038, TSE-000045, TSE-000046, TSE-000024, TSE-000022, TSE- 
000025, TSE-000028, TSE-000026, TSE-000017, TSE-000069, TSE-000054, TSE- 
000037, TSE-000018\') AND device_id = \'1\' AND date >= \'2018-05-02\' and 
date <= \'2018-05-02\' ;'
```

And as you can see the TSE-****** are all being considered as one argument. I am passing a dictionary to the execute() but the tuple for the named argument holding the TSE-****** values causes an error, and trying to use a string with the "'" already around them doesnt work due to it escaping them as well. I have tried all sorts of things with no luck. Any insight is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a `tuple` to expand the IN list:

```
sql = 'SELECT * FROM Compressor WHERE site_id IN %(sites)s'
cur.execute(sql, { 'sites': tuple(sites.keys()), })
```

Comment: When I attempt to pass a tuple like that is causes an error and will not allow for the tuple. I manually passed ('TSE-000018',) and that will work fine, however if I have more than 1 element in the tuple it errors out as in ('TSE-000018', 'TSE-000019) and I have no idea why it will not take it. 
Any other ideas?

Comment: This should work fine. What error do you get? Can you add an example dictionary and the code that calls `execute` to your question?

Comment: There was a syntax error in the prepared statement, your solution was correct. Can you explain how to get all of the matches for a like statement? I want it to pull all results where this is the case, not just the first one.

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're asking.  A query like this should return multiple rows, which you can iterate over with `for row in cur:`

Comment: SELECT site_id,site_name,date,time,* FROM "SiteInfoSchema"."Compressor" WHERE site_id in ('TSE-000032', ' TSE-000032', ' TSE-000030') AND device_id = 1 AND date >= '2018-05-02' AND date <= '2018-05-02' AND time >= '10:00' AND time <= '10:00' ;

Comment: The statement above returns only one row, the one matching the first element in the tuple, anything else it ignores. If i shuffle them around it returns only the first element.

Comment: Im using PGadmin for this currently actually, but i am using fetch_all() instead of one by one, this is for a summary

Comment: in PG admin I am only getting the first statement in the list to match, no others are populating. Is there another statement to make it pull them all instead of short circuiting at the first OR match?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170243/discussion-between-theodore-howell-and-andomar).

Comment: When I do this I get a nested tuple in the query, e.g. 'SELECT * FROM Compressor WHERE site_id IN (('Site1', Site2', Site3'))'. Note the double (( )). Any suggestions? I'm not using a nested tuple by accident or something like that. Seems a bug to me ... I'm using psycopg2-binary version  2.8.5.